# Refer to variable from a x-th function within a class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got the feeling that it is the time to start with classes. I have a file of such structure. And I can't access the variable set in **init**, how can I do it? Is my structure even correct? What now is described as multiple functions are three functions, 2 of them are able to work independently, so I thought it is a nice thing to put them in class so I can use them easily in another project. Functions are executed on the end of the class.

```
class args:
    def __init__(self):
        args = self.get_args()
        self._old = args.old
        self._new = args.new
        self._xml = args.xml

    @staticmethod
    def get_args():
        pass #too long to bother here

    @property
    def old(self):
        return self._old

    @property
    def new(self):
        return self._new

    @property
    def xml(self):
        return self._xml

class update:
    def __init__(self, print_dict = False):
        self.print_dict = print_dict

    def dict_of_glyph_order(old, new):
        pass

    def update_VTT_g_order(xml, glyph_id_dict, print_dict):
        if self.print_dict:
            print('%03d == %03d' %(int(glyph_id), int(new_id)), end=',  ')

    def save_new_xml(xml, tree):
        pass

    args = args()
    dict_of_glyph_order = dict_of_glyph_order(args.old, args.new)
    tree = update_VTT_g_order(args.xml, dict_of_glyph_order, self.print_dict) #variable called here
    save_new_xml(args.xml, tree)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    update()
```

Comment: This code is too pseudo to be useful. Can we have some real code?

Comment: @Aran-Fey I have put it there, please leave a note if you think that the structure is a mess. I recently failed at job interview due to the classes so I am practising it

Comment: Well, you went from too little to too much... Can you reduce that to a [mcve]?

Comment: @Aran-Fey sorry! This should be fine, so others can understand the problem

Comment: There are a couple of problems with this code... `args` is not defined, none of your 3 methods have a `self` parameter, and what is that code doing in the body of your class?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any compelling reason for `args` to exist yet; a tuple containing the three values of interest would be enough.

Comment: Sorry, but I think it's pretty clear you don't understand Python and/or classes well enough to use them, which makes it very difficult to answer your question about them in light of the sample code provided in it.

Comment: @martineau I think I understand Python clearly, what I say is that I haven't been using classes much, which got better. How can you judge someone that they don't understand Python by pseudocode? Classes are obviously something that doesn't make sense to implement for codes that are made for few uses only for only one person - my case. I think that it's time to move on and classes are what I am missing, that's why I am trying to learn it. I understood it better and all the comments have been very helpful. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: Jansindl3r: Sorry, didn't realize your were posting pseudocode. OK, so here's a tip about classes, when you call them, it runs the their `__init__()` method and the value returned ultimately returned is an instance of the class—so just calling `update()` like you're doing creates a class instance, but doesn't store it anywhere, so it's pretty useless. I also suggest you start out using normal attributes and wait to do begin using properties until you've got a good understanding of the latter.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are missing the name of the class, second, you declare the variables you are going to use IN the init method, you only need self in the parantheses for this method + the variables that you get from the outside of the class (), other auxiliary methods may need other variables declared like that if you want to use variables from the outside of the class, next, self. is mandatory in order to declare and use any variable that you use anywhere inside the class, you can have local variables that only exist in one method if you need them but you can only declare class variables within init, ultimately EVERYTHING within the class must be in a method , init or other, the class is not a method in itself, it is more like a custom variable tipe that you define and give build in methods to it, and you must make a variable of the defined tipe in order to use its functionalities.

```
class Some_name:     #no space allowed just underscore in the name
    def __init__(self,print_dict):
        self.print_dict = print_dict 
    def one_of_multiple_functions(some other variable):
        #the thing you want it to do
```

Example :

```
A=Some_name(print_dict)
A.one_of_multiple_functions(some other variable)  #in order to use the method
```

If you want some better axamples try SoloLearn, it is a mobile app that teaches you the basics of any popular programming language.